# How to Import Pandas in a VS Code Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, import, jupyter-notebook

I'm fairly new to coding, and all my previous experience has been with Jupyter Notebook, but I've been asked to switch to VS Code. I've installed the Jupyter and Python extensions, and I'm currently working in an ipynb file, where I can write and run regular code normally. However, when I try `import pandas as pd`, I get a ModuleNotFoundError saying that there's no module named 'pandas.' I tried `pip install pandas`, both in the VS Code terminal and the regular Mac terminal, but I'm still getting the error. I've also installed anaconda on my computer if that's relevant. Sorry, I'm sure it's a very simple error but I'm not familiar enough with this to understand how to import Pandas or other libraries. Any help is appreciated, and I'll try to respond promptly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Click on the kernel version in the upper right corner, and then select the kernel that installed `pandas`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the command %pip install pandas in the code cell.
[command syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHcsf.png)

Comment: For [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121), please do not post code as text. it is better to add code text to a codeblock. Thanks